# Why would the power sent in the first place for it to be reflected on say a transmitter if antenna is open, or a higher impedance antenna connected?

Tags: circuit-analysis, ac, antenna, impedance-matching, ham-radio

I'd really like to know in a fundamental way why power is said to be reflected during a mismatch and mainly if this is related to the maximum power transfer theorem. By that logic, if the load impedance was much higher, the total circuit impedance would be very high and so less current flowing so surely in an close to open antenna port, very little current would be flowing to cause ‘reflected’ power.

Comment: You're thinking about this like it's a DC circuit, which it's not.

Comment: @SteveSh Even then, RF theory can be applied at DC; it might just not be very meaningful or useful to do so, versus the usual DC analysis :)

Comment: You need to study transmission line theory

Comment: @SteveSh Always remember the real world does not classify itself nicely into "DC circuits" and "not DC circuits"; it's humans that invented "DC models" and "not DC models". Granted, the models are very good and you should definitely choose the most convenient one, which is not the DC model if you are analyzing a transmission line.

Answer (score 4):

What happens depends on the frequency of the signal you're transmitting. Let's consider the common case where the conductor (i.e. coax cable) is much longer than the wavelength of the signal. This means that the frequency is so high that we have to view the conductor as a so-called [transmission line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_line). (If this wasn't the case, you likely wouldn't be using coax.)

Electricity isn't infinitely fast - it only travels at most at the speed of light, and within a conductor (like our coax), it's even slower than that. This means that when you send the signal into one end of the coax, it doesn't appear at the other end immediately. As a result, the signal doesn't immediately "know" that the other end of the coax is open. Instead, the signal - and therefore a certain amount of electrical energy - begins to travel through the coax just as if it was connected properly. After a while, this packet of energy finally hits the unconnected end of the coax, which is like a brick wall for it (infinite resistance). Since there's nowhere for the energy to go, the amplitude (voltage) of the signal goes up as the energy piles up at the end of the coax, and this higher amplitude then causes the signal to get sent back the way it came.

As a very simple physical analogy, consider a very long piece of pipe with one open and one capped-off end. As you shout into the open end, the soundwaves initially travel into the pipe because they don't know that the other end is closed. Once they hit the capped end, they can't go any further and get reflected. After a while, the sound comes back out of the open end of the pipe - and you hear an echo.

The same happens to the unconnected coax. You shout a signal into it, and after a while, an echo of the signal comes back out.

When there's only an impedance mismatch (and not a full open / short circuit), only part of the signal's energy gets reflected. In the pipe analogy, you could consider the end to be only half-closed, causing a weaker echo since part of the sound energy can escape.

Comment: Thankyou so much, so my only question now is why the current would want to keep flowing to the end point in the first place? Like if the total circuit as a high resistance why would the be current flowing to the end point to be bounced off? Thanks

Comment: @Georgekirby The circuit doesn't have a high resistance for high-frequency signals due to the coax cable's characteristic impedance. For example, if you have a disconnected 50 Ohm coax cable, that cable still represents a 50 Ohm load to the signal source until the signal has traveled all the way to the end of the cable and reflected back to the source. And even when the signal's reflection has stabilized, the cable will still act as a complex impedance (for example as a capacitor or inductor to ground) due to the phase shift from the wire's length.

Comment: Thankyou so much i didnt really think of it that way, so the 50ohm impedance from the coax could then be thought of as in parralel to the source? And also what about if there is no coax or anything connected to say a transmitter, is the say 50ohm impedance this has treated as parralel then?